# list the identical words from fiel

Tags: shell-scripting

how can I list the identical words from below file using shell script ?

```
list.txt

LT
R
LT
MRTD
LT
MK
RR
RR
```

example result :

```
LT
R
MRTD
MK
RR
```

Comment: Your example result doesn't make sense R,MRTD and MK aren't duplicated ? Your Example result shows the unique 'words'. Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sort, and uniq like this:

```
 cat list.txt | sort | uniq
```

Comment: You don't need cat. `sort list.txt | uniq` works.

Comment: Gratuitous use of `cat` is gratuitous.

Comment: You are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` also has the `--unique` option:

```
$ sort -u list.txt
```